# Drop down menu items disappearing on hover

Tags: html, css

I have the following drop down:

CSS:

```
.third-menu{
    position: relative;
    top: -50px!important;
}


.dropdown-submenu {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}


#mn-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
    height: 30px;


}
.mn-sidebar {
  margin-left: 40px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
    background: #333333;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#mn-cont {
  display: block;
    vertical-align: top;     
    position: relative;
    padding: 10;
}
.container {
    margin-right: auto;
}
.cnt-mcont {
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding: 15px 30px 30px 30px;
  margin-top: 0;
    height: 101vh;
}
.mn-sidebar .mn-toggle {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.mn-vnavigation {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #CCFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCFFFF;
border-left: 5px solid #CCFFFF;
border-right: 5px solid #CCFFFF;

}
.mn-vnavigation li a {
  border-top: 2px solid #CCFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCFFFF;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 18px 13px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-submenu >
.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  /*height: 590px; */
  width: 300px;
  background: #333333;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover > 
.dropdown-menu {

    display: list-item;
}

.dropdown-submenu > a:after {

    display: list-item;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
ul.dropdown-menu.parent {
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Javascript in the fiddle.

Here's the jsfiddle:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpxVdv

Now, when I hover over the items, say on Central Compliance, then the remaining items below it (Control Room, Wealth Applications etc.) disappear. And if I over over Control Room, then Orchestria comes in the white space.

How can this be fixed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your css:

```
.third-menu{
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}


.dropdown-submenu {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't disapeare, the active item expands to have enought height to contain menu from next level. Try using `position:absolute` for next level container.